# C# validate XML against generated Xsd generated class

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

In our project, we have classes generated from XSD's. Currently we are validating the XML against the XSD by the XSD file path.

There are several XSD's and we select the right one by a number stored in the Database just like:

> "C:/Projects/XSD/Reports/Report_**1.7**.xsd"
>   "C:/Projects/XSD/Reports/Report_**1.8**.xsd"

Because I become a little bit nervous when it starts to have file paths in a project like this. Is there a best practice for this use-case? Something like validating the xml against the generated C# class directly. My current Code:

```
    private static string GetXsdPath(SchemaType aSchemaType, string aTransferRevision)
    {
        var lFileBeginnName = XsdStrategies.XsdService.GetXsdName(aSchemaType);
        var lDirectoryName = XsdStrategies.XsdService.GetDirectoryName(aSchemaType);
        string lRoot = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~");
        string lFullRootPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(lRoot, @"../"));

        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, @"{0}/Reports/{1}/Report_V{2}.xsd",
            lFullRootPath,
            lDirectoryName,
            aTransferRevision);
    }

    public bool IsValidXml(string aXmlContent, string aXsdFilePath, XNamespace aNamespaceName)
    {
        try
        {
            if (aNamespaceName == null)
            {
                this.Logger.AddLogEntry(LogLevel.Error, "Namespace is null.");
                return false;
            }

            var lXdoc = XDocument.Parse(aXmlContent);
            var lSchemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
            lSchemas.Add(aNamespaceName.NamespaceName, aXsdFilePath);

            // xDoc Validate throws an excption if xml not conforms xsd.
            lXdoc.Validate(lSchemas, null);
        }
        catch (XmlSchemaValidationException lEx)
        {
            this.Logger.AddLogEntry(LogLevel.Error, $"The Xml is not valid against the Xsd: {lEx}");
            return false;
        }
        catch (XmlSchemaException lEx)
        {
            this.Logger.AddLogEntry(LogLevel.Error, $"Therse is something wrong in the Schema-Version from Xml and Xsd: {lEx}");
            return false;
        }
        catch (XmlException lEx)
        {
            this.Logger.AddLogEntry(LogLevel.Error, $"A generic Error occured durring Xml against Xsd validation: {lEx}");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you store the XSD data directly in the database rather than just the path, you're very much correct that this is a bad idea.

You can store the XSD data in something like an NVarChar data type in MS SQL Server, for example.